# HTML5 e JavaScript - Múltiplos Vídeos Play/Pause

Tags: javascript, html5, html5-video

Fala pessoal tudo bem? Tenho uma página onde possuo 2 vídeos em HTML5, não estou usando nem um outro player. Gostaria de saber como consigo fazer com que quando clique em um vídeo e que, os outros não reproduzam todos ao mesmo tempo.

Na minha cabeça pensante seria um função que identificasse se o vídeo foi clicado, se está rodando e ou e já foi finalizado a reprodução dele.

Na NET tentei procurar em Inglês algo mas sem sucesso, vi muitos códigos e sem ideias.

Agradeço de coração se algum **STACK OVER NINJA** puder me dar uma força com isso!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Video</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="bg-light">
  <div class="container pt-4">
  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-7 text-center mx-auto">
        <h1 class="text-uppercase">Vídeos Exemplos</h1>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 pt-3">
        <video controls class="w-100 meus_videos">
                <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        <h3>Video 01</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6  pt-3">
        <video controls="" class="w-100 meus_videos">
                <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        <h3 class="text-right">Video 02</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Veja se entendi bem o que você quer: você tem 3 videos, e sempre reproduzir um por vez? É isso? Nunca deixar que mais de um vídeo esteja em reprodução?

Comment: Olá amigo, exatamente, bem isso que preciso. Teve um amigo que até comentou um exemplo mas não era exatamente o que precisava...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em todos os vídeos você adiciona a classe ***parado***:

```
<video controls class="w-100 meus_videos parado">
```

Sempre que começar a execução de um vídeo com a classe ***parado***, você dispara um evento:

```
$('.parado').on('play', function() {
```

Esse evento executa um laço que pega todos os vídeo que tiverem a classe ***rodando** e pausa o vídeo:

```
$(".rodando").each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('rodando').addClass('parado');
    $(this).get(0).pause();
});
```

Após pausar o vídeo, é atribuído a classe ***rodando*** para o vídeo que foi clicado e é dado play neste vídeo:

```
$(this).removeClass('parado').addClass('rodando');
$(this).get(0).play();
```

#### Segue código completo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Video</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="bg-light">
  <div class="container pt-4">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-7 text-center mx-auto">
        <h1 class="text-uppercase">Vídeos Exemplos</h1>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 pt-3">
        <video controls class="w-100 meus_videos parado">
                <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        <h3>Video 01</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6  pt-3">
        <video controls="" class="w-100 meus_videos parado">
                <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        <h3 class="text-right">Video 02</h3>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>  
        $( document ).ready(function($) {
            $('.parado').on('play', function() {
                $(".rodando").each(function(){
                        $(this).removeClass('rodando').addClass('parado');
                        $(this).get(0).pause();
                });
                $(this).removeClass('parado').addClass('rodando');
                $(this).get(0).play();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muito bom, era exatamente isso que precisava! Agradeço pelo tempo em responder e muito mais pelo tempo que em ficou em cima do desenvolvimento desta função!